# Java Convert Unicode String to English String

Tags: java, urlencode

I am new to java and i have characters like this

> "%6D%61%61%20%77%61%72%64%20%6C%6F%20%65%6E%6E%69%20%73%61%72%6C%75%20%68%6F%75%73%65%20%73%69%74%65%20%6B%6F%72%61%6B%75%20%61%70%70%6C%79%20%63%68%65%73%69%6E%61%20%6D%61%27%61%6D%20%65%74%75%76%61%6E%74%69%20%75%70%61%79%6F%67%61%6D%20%6C%65%6B%75%6E%64%61%20%69%6E%64%69%76%69%64%75%61%6C%20%70%6F%79%69%6E%64%69%20%74%72%79%20%63%68%65%79%61%6D%61%6E%74%61%72%61%61%20%76%61%64%69%6C%65%79%61%6D%61%6E%74%61%61%72%61%20%70%6C%65%61%73%65%20%73%65%6E%64%20%6D%65%20%61%6E%73%77%65%72"

When i try to convert them using this [tool](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php). i am able to convert to the values as desired.

converted results :

> "maa ward lo enni sarlu house site koraku apply chesina ma'am etuvanti upayogam lekunda individual poyindi try cheyamantaraa vadileyamantaara please send me answer"

but how can i do it using programmatically can someone help.

I tried this

```
String raw = "%6D%61%61%20%77%61%72%64%20%6C%6F%20%65%6E%6E%69%20%73%61%72%6C%75%20%68%6F%75%73%65%20%73%69%74%65%20%6B%6F%72%61%6B%75%20%61%70%70%6C%79%20%63%68%65%73%69%6E%61%20%6D%61%27%61%6D%20%65%74%75%76%61%6E%74%69%20%75%70%61%79%6F%67%61%6D%20%6C%65%6B%75%6E%64%61%20%69%6E%64%69%76%69%64%75%61%6C%20%70%6F%79%69%6E%64%69%20%74%72%79%20%63%68%65%79%61%6D%61%6E%74%61%72%61%61%20%76%61%64%69%6C%65%79%61%6D%61%6E%74%61%61%72%61%20%70%6C%65%61%73%65%20%73%65%6E%64%20%6D%65%20%61%6E%73%77%65%72";
String searchSection = new String(raw.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "UTF-8");
System.out.println( searchSection);
```

if this question is duplicate of any other question please point me in the right direction thanks

Converted text should match

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There isn't such a thing as a "Unicode string" or "English string" - **all** text is Unicode, and the task you are trying to perform has *nothing to do with* how Unicode works.  That might be why you were not able to find a proper solution with a search engine. Before you can decode anything, you must understand what kind of encoding is being used. Unicode encodings map between *raw bytes of data* and text. This encoding maps from one piece of text to another.

Comment: Most likely, the encoding you are looking for here is HTML "percent-encoding" or "url-encoding". You can tell this because of the pattern in the data: a `%` followed by two hexadecimal digits, over and over. Each of those groups of three characters represents a single character in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `URLDecoder.decode(yourMessage, "UTF-8")` from `java.net`:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String yourMessage = "%6D%61%61%20%77%61%72%64%20%6C%6F%20%65%6E%6E%69%20%73%61%72%6C%75%20%68%6F%75%73%65%20%73%69%74%65%20%6B%6F%72%61%6B%75%20%61%70%70%6C%79%20%63%68%65%73%69%6E%61%20%6D%61%27%61%6D%20%65%74%75%76%61%6E%74%69%20%75%70%61%79%6F%67%61%6D%20%6C%65%6B%75%6E%64%61%20%69%6E%64%69%76%69%64%75%61%6C%20%70%6F%79%69%6E%64%69%20%74%72%79%20%63%68%65%79%61%6D%61%6E%74%61%72%61%61%20%76%61%64%69%6C%65%79%61%6D%61%6E%74%61%61%72%61%20%70%6C%65%61%73%65%20%73%65%6E%64%20%6D%65%20%61%6E%73%77%65%72";

        try {
            System.out.println( URLDecoder.decode(yourMessage, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) { }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
maa ward lo enni sarlu house site koraku apply chesina ma'am etuvanti upayogam lekunda individual poyindi try cheyamantaraa vadileyamantaara please send me answer
```